# Unable to get property 'signalR' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, signalr

I am trying the SignalR intro sample from here: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-20

Following the sample, I got the error below after pressing F5:

> Unhandled exception at line 17, column 5 in
> http://myServer.com:12269/signalr/hubs
>
> 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime
> error: Unable to get property 'signalR' of undefined or null reference

I am new to SignalR, not quite sure where to start. Any insight?

A screenshot of the error. It's part of the generated hubs script.

[image]

The source code on the index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>SignalR Simple Chat</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .container {
            background-color: #99CCFF;
            border: thick solid #808080;
            padding: 20px;
            margin: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <input type="text" id="message" />
        <input type="button" id="sendmessage" value="Send" />
        <input type="hidden" id="displayname" />
        <ul id="discussion"></ul>
    </div>
    <!--Script references. -->
    <!--Reference the jQuery library. -->
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
    <script src="signalr/hubs"></script>
    <!--Add script to update the page and send messages.-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
            var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
            // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
            chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message) {
                // Html encode display name and message.
                var encodedName = $('<div />').text(name).html();
                var encodedMsg = $('<div />').text(message).html();
                // Add the message to the page.
                $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + encodedName
                    + '</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp;' + encodedMsg + '</li>');
            };
            // Get the user name and store it to prepend to messages.
            $('#displayname').val(prompt('Enter your name:', ''));
            // Set initial focus to message input box.
            $('#message').focus();
            // Start the connection.
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                    // Call the Send method on the hub.
                    chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
                    // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment.
                    $('#message').val('').focus();
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You get this error in your browser?

Comment: @Daniel Yes, I am using IE 10.

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: @Daniel I uploaded a screenshot of the error. The code are just copied from the sample link.

Comment: Do you load the good version of JQuery before loading the hub?

Comment: I guess I should have. Because it's all through the NuGet. I didn't do anything special.

Comment: Can you share the code where you load JQuery and where you define you connect the client to the hub?

Comment: @Daniel I just shared the page source code.

Comment: Just to be sure. Do you have the JQuery script file "jquery-1.6.4.min.js" in the script folder?

Comment: @Daniel Bingo! It turns out I am using totally different versions of jQuery 1.10.2 and singalR 2.0.0. After I change the version number, everything works now! If you post your answer, I will mark it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to reference the appropriate version of JQuery that you have in your Scripts folder.

Answer (score 2):

I face the same issue while working on 
http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr

really the issue is the copied HTML code from one of the instructions. the HTML refers to an older version of Jquery and jquery singnal R

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
<script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
<script src="signalr/hubs"></script>
```

update these values as per the current automatically loaded script versions as shown below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

jQuery (`$`) is not defined, so :

- it might not be loaded at all
- it might be loaded after the signalIR file
- you might be using [noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)

Answer (score 1):

The error has to do with jQuery, not SignalR.

Notice the error message says `Unable to get property 'signalR' of undefined or null reference`. How can we get `signalR` from an undefined or null object.

To fix, make sure you're attaching jQuery to the page properly.

Again: This has **nothing** to do with SignalR being naughty, but just a case of the missing jQuery library.

---

To test if jQuery is actually loaded, run this in your console:

```
console.log($);
```

You should get the standard jQuery output. If that doesn't work, try this. If this works, it means you're having an issue with conflicting variables.

```
console.log(jQuery);
```